# JSP + Eclipse java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when referencing other project

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat, noclassdeffounderror

first of all my code:

BotWeb.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>BotWeb</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div align="center" style="margin-top: 50px;"> 
  <form action="BotServlet">
   Bot input:  <input type="text" name="botInput" size="20px"> <br>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com    /xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
 <display-name>BotWeb</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>botweb.BotServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/BotServlet</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

BotServlet.java

```
public class BotServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private ChatBot bot = null;

    @Override
    public void init() {        
       if (bot == null) {
           bot = new ChatBot();
       }

        System.out.println("init is successful");
   }
   ...
   doGet, doPost etc. are omitted because it fails upon init()
```

What I'm trying to do:
I have a chatbot (that works, using program-ab), and I want to make a simple website to talk to the bot.
I'm using Eclipse and the chatbot is in another project (the page is it's own project). I can import from the other project fine, Eclipse shows no errors, the page loads with the input loads fine but when I input anything and click submit I get the following error:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet Hello threw exception

org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/alicebot/ab/AIMLProcessorExtension
botweb.BotServlet.init(BotServlet.java:20)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The missing class is used in the Bot project, where everything works fine. It is not a web project but rather a regular Java project, where I added the .jar (Ab.jar) to the build path and it has no trouble finding it.
Eclipse shows no errors in either of the two projects.

I tried various things, but none seem to work.
What I have done:
rightclick on page project -> properties -> Deployment Assembly -> added Bot project and hit apply
I have also added all of the Bot .jars to the page. rightclick project -> Build Path -> configure build path -> add external jars -> all of them
I also tried (after removing the jars from the build path again) to add them to the WEB-INF/lib folder. Again, same error.
I'm using Tomcat7 and Eclipse for the project, and as far as I can tell Tomcat works fine (page with input shows up, I can input and click the button but then I get the error)

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What do you mean by `It is not a web project but rather a regular Java project`? What artifact are you deploying? And is your Ab.jar contained within that artifact?

Comment: For the page I created a "Dynamic Web Project" in Eclipse, for the Bot it's a Java project. The Ab.jar is in the build path of the Bot project

Comment: I'm not sure how Eclipse works - what I mean is, that thing (`.war` file I'd guess) that gets deployed into Tomcat. Your `Ab.jar` needs to be available THERE - you can check it by opening that file with archive manager like 7zip.